How to disprove $(\forall a \in\mathbb R)(\exists x \in\mathbb R)\,x^2+ x = a$?

True or false: for all $a \in\mathbb R$, there exists $x \in\mathbb R : x^2+ x = a$?

This issue is false but I couldn't find a way to prove it.
I tried the $∆$ way; it brings three solutions to $a$, like this:

when $∆>0 : a>-1/4$
when $∆<0 : a<-1/4$
when $∆=0 : a=-1/4$.


$x^{2}+x \ge -\frac 1  4$ for all $x$.

But you already found the solution, right? Since a quadratic has a root only if $\Delta\ge 0$, your $x$ does not exist if $a<-1/4$.

@Al.G. Your comment could be an answer.

Hmm okay, moved it.

When mentioning techniques from a class such as the $\Delta$ way you should use the standard for that name technique, i.e. "the discriminant". Please make sure you include terminology like that (or ask when you dont know the terminology) in the future otherwise you will probably get a lot of negative reception.  Moreover you say "I tried the $\Delta$ way" and then don't even tell us what your conclusions from that are. I.E. you list the discriminants and then don't write out their logical conclusions (how many real roots are there). Please add that to the question.

Your approach makes no sense to me.
When trying to disprove a universally quantified statement, what we do is we provide a counterexample. In this case, it means we name a particular $a$ which is not of the form $x^2 + x$. Here, what we want is a sufficiently large negative number. I'll go with $a = - 10$, and argue that there cannot be a matching $x$.
We note that $x^2 + x = (x + 1)x$, so for $x^2 + x$ to be negative, we need that exactly one of $(x + 1)$ and $x$ is negative. Thus, we have that $x < 0 < x + 1$, hence $-1 < x < 0$. But this implies $-1 < x^2 + x$, so $x^2 + x$ cannot be $-10$.

The first sentence is maybe a little harsh? And in fact, from the OP's table it follows immediately that there is no solution for any $a<-\frac14$, so it's a sensible direction to go

@Milten I literally mean that I have no clue what is going on. Maybe I would understand if I had been in OPs class and knew what the "$\Delta$ way"is meant to be, but without such context it is just a symbol appearing out of no-where.

That’s fair. Well, for what it’s worth they are writing $\Delta$ for the discriminant of the quadratic. (But no need to discuss further on my account)

But you already found the solution, right? Since a quadratic has a root only if $\Delta\ge0$, your $x$ does not exist if $a<−1/4$.

Note that $$x^2+x=a\iff\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=a+\frac{1}{4}.$$
Thus, if you want to disprove $$\forall \left(a\in\Bbb R\right)\exists \left(x\in\Bbb R\right)\left(\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=a+\frac{1}{4}\right)$$, you have to prove that $$\exists \left(a\in\Bbb R\right)\forall \left(x\in\Bbb R\right)\left(\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\neq a+\frac{1}{4}\right).$$
Choose $a=-\frac{5}{4}$ (or any $a<-\frac{1}{4}$) and let $x\in\Bbb R$ be arbitrary. Since
$a+\frac{1}{4}=-1$ and $\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\geq0,$
it follows that $$\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\neq a+\frac{1}{4},$$
what was to be shown.
